# Concatenating, sorting, and re-partitioning xyz data

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have a situation where I have two lists of [x, y, z] data, I want to concatenate these lists, sort them, then extract a matrix for the z values, with x increasing along the columns, and y increasing along the rows.

To give an example:

```
list1 = np.linspace(-2,2,3)
list2 = np.linspace(-1,1,3)

dat1 = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list1:
        z = x * y
        dat1 += [[x,y,z]]

dat1 = np.array(dat1)

dat2 = []
for x in list2:
    for y in list2:
        z = x * y
        dat2 += [[x,y,z]]

dat2 = np.array(dat2)
```

I can build an array from the z values for each of these list individually using:

```
dat1[:, 2].reshape((list1.shape[0],list1.shape[0]))
```

but I want an (ordered) array for all values from both lists, i.e. I want to do the same thing with full sorted data set:

```
dat_full=np.vstack((dat1, dat2))
dat_index = np.lexsort((dat_full[:,1], dat_full[:,0]))
dat_sorted = dat_full[dat_index]
```

the problem is that this is not a square array anymore, so I can't use the simple reshape trick I used previously. Is there a good way to do this?

**Edit:**

I should clarify that I am only interested in the unique data in concatenated array, which can be found using:

```
dat_full=np.unique(np.vstack((dat1, dat2)))
dat_index = np.lexsort((dat_full[:,1], dat_full[:,0]))
dat_sorted = dat_full[dat_index]
```

Comment: I think it will not be possible to do this easily with numpy since the result will not be a matrix at all. If I understood the problem correctly the result is gonna be a list of arrays, that differ in length. I think you're gonna have to do this 'by hand'.

Comment: I should clarify that I am only interested in unique values of the sorted data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [markuscosinus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10960882) said, the problem with this is that you would need a "matrix" with varying row and column sizes, which cannot be done in NumPy. The alternative that you may consider, however, is using a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), if you can work with that. That will allow you to have all the values in the same array and masking the "gaps" as invalid. For example, you could do that like this (I have changed how you create `dat1` and `dat2` but the result is the same):

```
import numpy as np

list1 = np.linspace(-2, 2, 3)
list2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 3)
# Evaluate using grids instead of loops
xg1, yg1 = np.meshgrid(list1, list1, indexing='ij')
x1, y1 = xg1.ravel(), yg1.ravel()
xg2, yg2 = np.meshgrid(list2, list2, indexing='ij')
x2, y2 = xg2.ravel(), yg2.ravel()
dat1 = np.stack([x1, y1, x1 * y1], axis=-1)
dat2 = np.stack([x2, y2, x2 * y2], axis=-1)
# Full dataset
dat_full = np.concatenate([dat1, dat2])
# Remove repeated rows
_, idx = np.unique(dat_full, return_index=True, axis=0)
dat_uniq = dat_full[idx]
# Find unique X and Y values
_, x_idx, x_counts = np.unique(dat_uniq[:, 0], return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
_, y_idx, y_counts = np.unique(dat_uniq[:, 1], return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
# Make array as big as the most repeated index
result = np.zeros((x_counts.max(), y_counts.max()), dtype=dat_full.dtype)
# Make mask for array
mask = np.ones_like(result, dtype=bool)
# Fill array and mask
result[x_idx, y_idx] = dat_uniq[:, 2]
mask[x_idx, y_idx] = False
# Make masked array
result = np.ma.masked_array(result, mask)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[4.0 -- -0.0 -- -4.0]
 [-- 1.0 -0.0 -1.0 --]
 [-0.0 -0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -1.0 0.0 1.0 --]
 [-4.0 -- 0.0 -- 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be

```
result = []
_, occurences = np.unique(dat_sorted[:,0], return_inverse=True)

for i in range(np.max(occurences) + 1):
    result.append(dat_sorted[occurences == i, 2])
```

This will give you a x value ordered list of y value ordered arrays of z values. This is not a matrix because there are x values occuring more often than others, resulting in different sized arrays.